# What alien was forced to control that superweapon?

Tags: star-trek, weapon, star-trek-enterprise, mind-control

Some Enterprise ep had an alien I remember was forced (and kidnapped?) to command a system with their mental abilities, strapped and trapped in a chair looking dead in control.

If it helps, if i remember, it was maybe Romulans(?) kidnapping an Andorian(?). I keep trying to search.

I can't remember what point and what character to research. What reminds me to find it is how forced it was, whole theme was detailed and well-enacted.

Any detail, vid, links you can share I appreciate.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Believe that's the three part episode [Babel One](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Babel_One), [United](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/United_%28Star_Trek:_Enterprise%29) and [The Aenar](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Aenar).  The Romulans capture an [Aenar](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/Aenar) (an Andorian sub-species) who they use (forcibly) to telepathically control a Romulan ship capable of disguising itself as whatever type of vessel the Romulans choose.  In Babel One, it's disguised as an Andorian ship and attacks the Enterprise.  The United and The Aenar episodes continue the storyline.

[image: Aenarian machined]
[image: Aenarian dead]